# elevation has correct range in metadata, but shows 0 for pixel values

Tags: raster, arcmap, elevation

IMG elevation raster lists correct maximum and minimum values (811.958, -410.72) and average (110), but no matter which type of symbology is chosen, all pixels display as 0. What do I need to do to get the pixel value displayed to correspond to the band 1 value? This is only a 1 band raster.

The no-data feature is set as a different value outside the range so that is not the issue.

I am using ArcMap 10.8, do not currently have spatial analyst

[image]

Comment: Can you share a picture of the problem? If you use the identify tool and click on a pixel, what are the values?

Comment: Pic added, thanks.  0 value but in the meta data we find the range and the mean is 110, so not sure if the file i received is bad or the issue is on my end

Comment: Appreciate the picture being added. Would you be able to share the image? I'd like to inspect it on my end.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that! I see where you are having problems. I am also having those problems. I looked at the properties so far and found a lot of zeros stored in the cells as well as nonzeros (hence your range). I also took a look at the histogram. Bare with me and I'll let you know what I find.

Comment: I apologize, but I was not able to find the problem. Can you provide me with where you obtained this data?

Comment: The file was sent to me by an agency official.  Were you able to display a legitimate elevation that was not just a lot of zeros?  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I was not able to display anything else other than zero. I tried reading it as an array through python/gdal, but I do not have enough memory to do so. I noticed that the nodata value was set as the min value which was interesting. I'd recommend trying to reach back out to the agency official to see what is happening. I apologize for not being more helpful.